# How do you set the scroll bar skin on a single List instance?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4

I've created a scrollbar skin that I'm able to apply to all List components using the following CSS:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    s|List s|HScrollBar {
        skinClass: ClassReference("com.skins.myScroller.MyHorizontalScrollerSkin");
        fixedThumbSize:true;
    }

</fx:Style>
```

The design has changed and now I need to apply this skin to only one List instance. How do I do this (preferring CSS or inline if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a class selector for the specific List, like this:

```
.myList s|VScrollBar {
    skinClass: ClassReference("net.riastar.skin.VScrollBarSkin");
}

<s:List styleName="myList" />
```